# invalid argument supplied for foreach() laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to show a book's comments by ISBN (book table's PK) and I get the following error:

[Invalid argument supplied for foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9MSD.png)

I'm using Laravel relationship and a foreach to get the records from the following query, in a Helper class:

```php
function getCommentsByISBN($data)
{    
    foreach (Book::where("ISBN", $data)->get() as $comments) {
        return $comments->comments;
    }
}
```

And here's my Book model, comment relationship:

```php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, "ISBN", "ISBN");
}
```

And here's the view where I show the comments:

```
@foreach(getCommentsByISBN(session("isbn")) as $comment)
    <div class="form-group">
        <h3>
            {{ getUserWhoPostedComment($comment->email) }}
        </h3>
        <p>
            {{ $comment->commentary }}
        </p>
        @if(Session::has("username") && isAdmin(session("username")))
            <button type="button" onclick="openModal('{{$comment->commentary}}')"
            name="warningButton" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#modalWarning">
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
            </button>
        @endif
        <hr>
        <span>
            Hace: {{ getTimeWherePostedComment($comment->publicated_at) }}
        </span>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the ```Book::where("ISBN", $data)->get()``` returns an array? You haven't given information about this function, that's why I am asking.

Comment: Where exactly is the error? In the first code or in the last code? I am not familiar with laravel but I think it might be just a little PHP error that might have to do nothing with laravel...

Comment: This helper looks weird. Why are you using helper in a first place? It should be in controller. Also, why in this helper is foreach? It will stop at first loop, so why there is even loop? If you want to get single model then just use ->first(). You need to redo this code. It would be good idea to start with some laravel course :) Good luck!

Comment: @chojnicki thanks for advice. I'm new using Laravel, and I have just made a course about it, but I know I can get more knowledge about it.

Comment: @chojnicki I'm not sure how can I add the code in the controller, because the method's controller where I "redirect" to the view is this

  public function showBookInfo()
    {

        return redirect(route("book.discover"))->with("isbn", request("discover"));

    }

Maybe I can return the view instead redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you helper **returns void** because no book was found with that ISBN.

I think it should look like this btw

```php
function getCommentsByISBN($isbn)
{
    if ($book = Book::where("ISBN", $isbn)->first()) {
        return $book->comments;
    }
}
```

and in your blade your top should look like

```
@php
     $comments = getCommentsByISBN(session("isbn")) ?: [];
@endphp
@foreach($comments as $comment)
   <div class="form-group">
   /// Rest of the code
```

Comment: This help me to avoid the "invalid argument etc..." error. But now, when I return the view, return back or redirect to the page where I show the book info with comments, they aren't there. Also, when I reload, the page get empty, there is no book's info, even creating a session to prevent this... 

EDIT:

It's okay... I wasn't creating the session variable properly, instead this, I was passing a flash session variable. Thank you very much!!!!